# What are the obstacles for a complex to be a space of loops?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, classifying-spaces, loop-spaces

It is known that any space of loops is an H-space. So my question has two parts:

1. What are the obstacles for a complex to be an H-space? Is there any hope to somehow reasonably classify/characterize all H-spaces?
2. What are the obstacles for an H-space to be a loop space?

Comment: Every loop space is an H-space, so Adams's resolution of the Hopf invariant 1 problem shows that $S^0, S^1, S^3$ and $S^7$ are the only spheres that are loop spaces. And is it really true that all H-spaces are loop spaces?

Comment: Oh, really, I mixed up the direction of inclusion and asked a stupid question.

Comment: I changed the question, thanks

Comment: All H-spaces have abelian $\pi_1$ and vanishing Whitehead products. These are your primary obstructions.

Comment: The multiplication on a loopspace is always homotopy associative, while on an H-space it need not be, e.g. $S^7$.

Comment: @Tyrone But these conditions are not yet sufficient, right? Maybe you can refer me to some literature? (I know that $π_1$ is abelian from Hatcher, yes).

Comment: Relevant https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127372/proving-that-a-space-cannot-be-delooped?rq=1